# How to speed up DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses

Tags: visual-studio

We are having a main UI application that starts additional (worker) processes where the real processing work is done. The UI needs to be used, because the configuration of the process very hard and needs a lot of knowledge.

Even during development, the UI must be used. The problem is that the UI is the primary startup which means that the debugger is attached to the UI process. The problem now is that the developers need to debug the worker process but the Visual Studio debugger is not attached.

So we did a few things to discover the running Visual Studio instance (which takes around 50ms) and attach the running Visual Studio debugger to the new worker process. In general the solution works, but the problem is that Visual Studio has its own notion of a process (`VSProcess`) which does not match to the regular `Process`.

So it is necessary to discover the `VSProcess` by searching for the process ID in the `Debugger.LocalProcesses`. This is very time consuming and on our system this takes more than 5 seconds, which is too long for an effective development. Obviously Visual Studio builds an internal list when accessing the `Debugger.LocalProcesses`. So when doing this repetitively a lot of time wasted for waiting for an obvious thing.

The only problem I have is that I need to match the `Process ID` with the `VSProcess ID`. If there would another way, for example if there would be a simple method, lets say `GetVSProcessForProcessId()` that would maybe already help a lot.

It would already help a lot if I could discover the LocalProcesses in a seperate thread but since the VS instance is running in STA there is no chance to do so.

Has someone experience in doing something similar and has similar problems?